# "generator-jhipster-material" ported to latest?

Tags: jhipster

I am trying to use the generator-jhipster-material to generate the Jhipster in combination with Bootstrap material design and I was not successfull in achieving it.

Does the "generator-jhipster-material" has been ported to latest Angular 4, Jhipster 4, Bootstrap 4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because last publication is from one year ago (before Angular 2+ support was added to Jhipster)